# Apache Arrow connectivity issue with HDFS (Remote file-system)

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow, pyhdfs-client

I want to  connect pyarrow to read to and write parquet file in hdfs
But I am facing some connectivity issue

I installed pyarrow and python pandas now I am trying to connect with hdfs
in remote machine

Reference link - https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-apache-arrow-with-apache-spark-and-pandas-bb19ffe0ddae

```
import pyarrow as pa
host = '172.17.0.2'
port = 8020
fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host, port)
```

Error messages

> ```
> >>> fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host, port)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 211, in connect
>     extra_conf=extra_conf)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 36, in __init__
>     _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath()
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 136, in _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath
>     classpath = _hadoop_classpath_glob('hadoop')
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 161, in _hadoop_classpath_glob
>     return subprocess.check_output(hadoop_classpath_args)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
>     process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
>     errread, errwrite)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: It seems like the Hadoop client libraries are not installed on this machine. Are they installed and can you invoke `hadoop` or `hdfs` on the command line?

Comment: Yes they installed and i also set HADOOP_HOME,ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR and CLASSPATH